# Send email using html button javascript and Rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

Im new to using rails and i have a test where im given a code that send an email through a click and i have to compleate it,

Here is the code:

app/views/root/index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag root_path, class: "send-email" do %>
  <%= submit_tag "Click to Send Email", style: "margin: 10px; padding: 10px" %>
<% end %>

<script>
document.querySelector(".send-email").onsubmit = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()

  fetch(e.target.action, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "X-CSRF-Token": document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content
    }
  }).then(function(response) {
    if (response.ok) {
      window.open('/mail', '_blank')
    } else {
      console.error(response)
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

How can i fix this to be able to send an email when clicking ?

Comment: What exactly is broken about it?

Comment: It does need an ajustement on the program to be able to send a message when i click, basicaly it needs the code for the email part